# Extending the $\text{SU}(2)\times \text{SU}(2)$ Lorentz group representation to SU(4) operations?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, group-representations

It's well known that in the (1/2,1/2) SU(2)xSU(2) representation of Lorentz group representation, the rotation and boost transformations correspond to the SU(2)xSU(2) operations. Or the SU(2)xSU(2) operation has a physically meaningful correspondence.

I am wondering if we extend the SU(2)xSU(2) operation to SL(2)xSL(2) and SU(4), are the operations in SL(2)xSL(2) and SU(4) also have meaningful physical correspondence (so we get an extension of the Lorentz transformation)?

What kind of physical transformation might a SL(2)xSL(2) or SU(4) operation lead to?

NOTE: This is not a duplication of my [previous post here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333467/2451). There I am trying to find out the relationship between the Lorentz group and a 2 qubit system so that the Lorentz group can be generated by a subset $V \in SU(4)$ of the unitary operation SU(4) on the 2 qubit system. The operations in this special subset $V$ of SU(4) have physically meaningful physical pictures(Lorentz transformations). Here I am trying to ask if all the other SU(4) operations or the operations in SL(2)xSL(2) also have physically meaningful correspondence as some kind of transformations on spacetime 4-vectors.  They are related questions, but they focus on different aspects of a system.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OPs: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333467/2451

Comment: Hi X. Dong. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Hi, I think it's a new question.  Here I am interested in the physical meaning of all the SU(4) operations, I am trying to understand what kind of spacetime transformation corresponds to a general SU(4) operation.  It's different from my original question,where I try to find out how to represent the complete (proper + improper) Lorentz group.

Comment: To represent the complete Lorentz group, we need all the SU(2)xSU(2) operations and some special SU(4) operations (to represent parity,time reversal transformations).   Here I am thinking about  all the other SU(4) operations.  I do not see it's a duplication of my previous post. This is an extended question.

Comment: My previous question is : Is Lorentz group is generated by a subset of SU(4)?    If yes, then this question is a new question: Is every operation  in SU(4) leads to a meaningful spacetime transformation? How to understand those transformations as an extension of Lorentz transformations?

Comment: Also you have a reopen vote in your own post.